# Show a website on modal when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying something which is kinda easy but im having some problems with it and i would like to get done it today.

I have a website page which has the following:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn1" data-toggle="modal" href="https://teespring.com/es/camiseta-gymsroka-deportiva?tsmac=store&tsmic=sroka-merchandising-2#pid=373&cid=100035&sid=front" data-target="#myModal" >Pedir ahora</button>
```

I have an eventListener with jQuery like this:

```
$('.btn1').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $(".modal-body").html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" src="'+url+'"></iframe>');
            });
```

so when the button is clicked it loads a modal and inside that modal it loads the wanted site on the href attribute, my modal coda btw is this:

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="myModal">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
   <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Pretty easy modal. Well the problem it comes when i click the button, on chrome it works, it opens the modal and it loads the url correctly, but it says few errors on the console.log like this:

```
Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'https://teespring.com/es/camisa-de-tirantes-gymsroka?tsmac=store&tsmic=sroka-merchandising-2#pid=408&cid=100232&sid=front': 'ALLOW-FROM https://www.facebook.com' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.
```

in firefox it tells me the error but it doesn't load anything...

How i can fix this? If there is a possible fix or how you guys would have made this? My objective is to have few items on my website and "sell" them to the users, but the sell process is made by another company so its easier and cheaper for me. How i can do it? Thank you team!

Comment: It would appear your vendor's Content Security Policy doesn't allow its site to be `iframe`d.

Answer (score 1):

That error occurs because the website you are trying to load inside the Iframe is denying access to load using http headers.

The website should allow that by configuring the X-Frame-Options header

You can read more here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: This is likely the correct answer. Tangentially, you'll probably have a hard time convincing a large vendor to allow frames from a low- or medium-traffic domain.